# Paypal Express Checkout - VAT is not shown neither on the form nor on backend

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using REST API to enable Paypal option on my site. To help the finance department for future taxation issues, I am trying to set up VAT rates based on the country.

After googling a bit and checking the documentation, found out Paypal's tools for setting the sales tax - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9ED090WS

But after setting the value on the config page like this: [image: tax config page]

I still cant see any tax information while I am trying to buy some test items (I had to cover some parts of the screenshots :/ )

[image]
[image]

And after a successful test purchase, I get `tax=0.00` in the IPN response.

Am I missing some points on the documentation about using the auto-tax calculator of Paypal?  Even setting taxing data while sending request to Paypal does not let me see the taxing information and other details on the form.

Comment: Had the same problem. Try taxamo. I'm using it comply with new EU law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal's tax calculator is a free tool included with PayPal Payments Standard; it doesn't work with any of the API based products. You will need to calculate tax and pass it to PayPal in the API call.

Comment: how to pass the vat amount. Can I pass it as an item description ?

Comment: Look into PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT, L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMTm
 https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/